# Are Huawei nova Y90 ROMs for model CTR-LX2 interchangeable with CTR-LX1?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, huawei, compatibility

I have a Huawei nova Y90 (CTR-LX2). I've been wanting to flash it with either a custom or stock ROM for experimental purposes, but I can't find a ROM file/firmware for the model CTR-LX2 specifically. I could mostly find for model CTR-LX1.

So far, I've only downloaded CTR-LX1, which has the `UPDATE.APP` file in it which, from searching on Google, is the file I need to flash. And I stumbled across a CTR-LX2 which was being sold on the net. When I took a look at it, it contained a `Super.img`. I wasn't sure how to flash that one as there wasn't any info on `Super.img`.

I was wondering if it's safe to flash the device with the CTR-LX1 ROM file or if my device will get bricked?

Comment: Flashing the wrong firmware will most likely brick. PS - Don't ask here for ROMs, it's off-topic.